# De-allocating structures in c?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc

I have many structures, one of which looks like

```
typedef int Info;  
typedef struct  
{  
    Info info;  
} Item;
```

So if I allocate like so:

```
ItemRef a;  
a= malloc(sizeof(ItemRef));
```

where `ItemRef` is just typecasted `int`.

My question is if I deallocate `a` now, will `info` inside it also be deallocated?

Because when I tried assigning vale to info in a and then deallocating is and then printing it I was still able to access the value.

So does that mean deallocating a structure does NOT deallocate its components ? Even though I didn't have to individually allocate the components?

Comment: Just because you can access the value doesn't mean that the system isn't allowed to write over it at any time. The system doesn't clean up the bits when you deallocate.

Comment: +1 for @KshitijMehta. Also what's `ItemRef`? Your code of `ItemRef a; a= malloc(sizeof(ItemRef)); ` looks quite weird.

Comment: Just because you was able to do something doesn't mean it is legal to do it.

Comment: Every `malloc` gets a corresponding `free`.  That's all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Deallocating a struct does deallocate the space for its members. However the rules of the C language do not require that the freed memory is zeroed out or made inaccessible in any way. All freeing does is tell the memory manager that you've finished with that bit of memory and it can reuse it at its discretion.

So, in a typical implementation, if you still have a pointer to the freed memory the compiler won't do anything to stop you accessing it.  Doing so puts you in the realm of **undefined behaviour** which means anything can happen.  Messing up in this way and accessing freed memory is a source of annoying and difficult to find bugs in C programs because the behaviour is often not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

From http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/free.html

> The free() function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated; that is, **made available for further allocation**. If ptr is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not
>   match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc(), malloc(), realloc()
>   or valloc() function, or if the space is deallocated by a call to
>   free() or realloc(), the behaviour is undefined. **Any use of a pointer
>   that refers to freed space causes undefined behaviour.**

As per the documentation, the `free` doesn't initializes all the memory bits, it freed, to any value. Thus the memory (might) still contain the old value. but its undefined behavior to refer it as stated.
The best practice is to::

```
free(a) ;
a = NULL ;
```

Comment: According to the standard, use of a pointer that was free results in undefined behavior.  That is, anything could happen.  In practice, compiler writers do what is most efficient, which is to mark the block that was freed as available for allocation, but otherwise not touch it.  Thus attempts to access will see the old value, prior to freeing, as the questioner was wondering about.  In the case of this question, the "why is this happening" has as much to do with the pragmatics of implementation as the standard itself.

Comment: @StevenBurnap:: Very true.